# jQuery .click for multistep form. Doesn't work when clicking buttons

Tags: jquery, forms

New to JavaScript/jQuery. I know HTML OK and CSS OK. Can't get my buttons to work in jQuery. Researching for 2 nights and now reaching out for help :( thnx

```
//jQuery time

$(document).ready(function () { });

var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets

$(".next").click(function () {
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();        
});

$(".previous").click(function () {
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
});

$(".submit").click(function () {

})
```

Comment: You need to put all your code inside `$( document ).ready(function() { <var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs ..........rest of your code>});` for the click events to work.

Comment: Can you put your html here?

Answer (score 0):

All your jQuery code should come within `$(document).ready(function () { });`

So you have to do something like this

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
$(document).ready(function () { 



    $(".next").click(function () {
        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        next_fs = $(this).parent().next();        
    });

    $(".previous").click(function () {
        current_fs = $(this).parent();
        previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
    });

    $(".submit").click(function () {

    });

});
```